# What is "ホラね、あった" referring to?

Tags: translation, meaning, words, slang

The scenario is two friends talking on a cell phone, A tells B she wants to tailor a piece of clothing, B offers to give her materials, A kindly declines the offer saying she'll find the materials herself but B scolds her for this, B also says this when scolds A:

> 材料なんてこのへんに…ホラね、あった！

I know ホラ can mean "see!" or "I told you so" but I'm not sure if it applies to the above context since it doesn't seem to make sense? Does it take on a different meaning here?

Answer (score 1):

ほら can be simple "hey!" and/or "look!":

> - ほら見て！ Hey look!
> - ほら、あそこ！ Look, over there!

It's also used as an interjection that means "see? I told you so!", "just as I said!" on its own.

> - ほらー。／ほらね？　I told you! / As I expected!

In your example it's used in this (second) sense. So in this context B wants to convince A that she doesn't have to find her material by herself because B already has one. B said ホラ because B confirmed his/her opinion was right.